# ImportError: cannot import name Lock

Tags: python-3.x

I finished the code yesterday and ran it well. But after some other process on another code document, the previous code doesn't work. What funny is, as I learned from some answers on the website, if I change the wheel import sequence, the error result will be different.

I have tried reinstalled python. But it doesn't work.

Code 1: 
       `import numpy as np
    import scipy.integrate
    import pandas as pd
    print(np.mean(1+3))`

Code 2:
       `import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.integrate
    print(np.mean(1+3))`

Comment: You have a `threading.py` file that is being found instead of the standard module of that name - notice its path is rather different than all the other modules.  It needs to be moved or renamed.

Comment: It works. Thank you.